# In Reactjs, how to send and respond to user defined event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In reactjs, how to send user defined event? and response to user defined event? Can you please give an example? e.g. user.newItemAddToCart

Below code is example for responding standard DOM event.

```
var AddFriend = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      newFriend: ''
    }
  },
  updateNewFriend: function(e){
    this.setState({
      newFriend: e.target.value
    });
  },
  handleAddNew: function(){
    this.props.addNew(this.state.newFriend);
    this.setState({
      newFriend: ''
    });
  },
  render: function(){
    return (
        <div>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.newFriend} onChange={this.updateNewFriend} />
          <button onClick={this.handleAddNew}> Add Friend </button>
          <span onUser.newItemAddToCart= {...}> does this work?</span>
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by user defined event?

Comment: Looks like you really should learn about HTML and javascript event handlers first. Compare the line `<span...` (incorrect) with the line `<button...` (correct) and look up (Google) how to define event handlers..

Comment: I know event handler in javascript and DOM, but can't figure how to do it in react.